# The image cannot be displayed because it contains error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display a background image  within a div :

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="fill-screen" style="background-image: url('../../wwwroot/images/lake.jpg');" ></div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

but , it dosen't get rendred !, when i dubug the browser with F12 and click the image Url i get this error :

[image]

what is wrong ?

Comment: My guess is that the image file is invalid/corrupted. Can you open it and see the image? Also, where is this code running?

Comment: no i can visualize it if i use <img src=""/> instead of div so it is not corrupted.
this code is running on the index.cshtml file

Answer (score 1):

Change the image like below:

```
background-image: url('../images/lake.jpg');
```

Or

```
background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/images/lake.jpg")')
```

Comment: Is the error still there? There is no content in your div now. You can fill it with some content to see if the background image is rendered.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is with your div class="container-fluid">
Link there your cointainer-fluid css code!

Comment: you mean i should put the background-image in the div that contains class="container-fluid' ? i did that but nothing have changed

Comment: In the css file at the container flui { } section